# Remove all the spaces at the bottom of elements

Tags: css, sass, compass

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. I have to remove all the padding and margin at the bottom of all html elements that are before the footer, so that I can add an specific margin between the footer and the last element.

Here is the HTML

```
<main id="main".....
   <div class="main-row"...
      <div class="main-page"
<footer class="footer"....
```

And here is my CSS

```
#main {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;

  .main-row {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;

      .main-page {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;

        .row {
          margin-bottom: 0;
          padding-bottom: 0;

          .column {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
```

Is this a good solution for the problem? or is this too complicated?

Comment: the question is : why all these margin/padding are set initially ? i guess there is a reason ... don't think it's a default behavior. And if you end up doing something like this means there is something wrong on the CSS or HTML structure

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well.. that is out of my control. UX team decided that they want for all pages the same height from the footer to the last element that appears on a page. So some elements have different paddings and margins depending on the last element that was rendered

Comment: so in this case i would use negative margin on the footer depending on each page ... but this still remain a bit strange. As we should not end up doing such thing if the CSS is well structred. We should for example have a reset class that we apply in some case to obtain such behavior for example. But it don't think it's bad what you did if it's needed ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, well I am asking is because for me personally looks weird, it does what it has to do, because not all the elements on the pages have the same padding and margin values. So I thought that maybe there is a better way to do this. Thank You!

Comment: it looks weird to me too that's why I am commenting :) and it's more weird when you said *not all the elements on the pages have the same padding and margin values* which means that your CSS is a bit complex. Also `better` is relative, personally i cannot give you a clear answer since i don't know the whole CSS as maybe there is another better way than reseting padding/margin

Comment: I totally understood what you're try to achieve, it's doable if the all pages are pretty simple, but once it involves multi-level nested elements or user input data then things will get complicated, my best advice for you is to convince the designer to drop this requirement.

Comment: @Stickers Thanks! Indeed the ticket for this task was dropped because like you said it was becoming complicated as code evolves

Answer (score 1):

The code as written is hard to maintain. I would style my elements in #main to make sense with the code and deal with the last element's bottom margin instead of clearing everything.

To do things similar to your starting code you could try something like this ( or an html reset ) to clear all elements.

I'm just targeting #main here.

```
#main * { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

If you'd like to get rid of just the last child's spacing you can try targeting them.

```
#main *:last-child { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, the problem is that inside that #main, there are also , buttons and other type of elements, if I reset all, then all those elements will look odd. I guess the solution works, it just looks terrible :s

Comment: `it just looks terrible` means it doesn't work in my book! I think you are on the right track with Temani.

Answer (score -1):

It is a ok solution. The better way to do this is in the below code.

```
#main, .main-row, .main-page, .row, .column {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: May do the trick for op but  the resulting css and behavior here is different, the code above ensures that these are all child elements of `#main`

Comment: `You have to do this for each one` so i guess her initial code is better at the end ...

Comment: First because the first code is different from the OP code and your second attempt is not better, you will simply repeat the declaration as many times as the OP code .. so i don't see any improvement.